# ActionMailer alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

i have been using actionmailer, but i always found it to be heavy and unintuitive.

Do you guys know of other solutions that are lighter and more intuitive?

Comment: What *specifically* do you not like about actionmailer?  I'm not defending it, just looking for more info on which to base any other recommendations.

Comment: I agree with @Max Williams. Please be more specific with your question. "Heavy and unintuitive" is very subjective a problem. Have you tried the Rails 3 api? It's much easier. Also i'm not aware of an alternative to ActionMailer like ActiveRecord.

Comment: i think the answer below answered it. I found the need to define a seperate HTML file for it overkill in many cases. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: for example, sometimes all i want is a quick email on the go. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [Pony](https://github.com/benprew/pony) gem (as in Pony Express), which is a lightweight alternative to ActionMailer:

```
require 'pony'
Pony.mail(:to => 'user@example.com', :from => 'railsapp@example.com',
          :subject => 'Hello From Rails')
```